# Angular 4, Use ngModel in Form Array (ReactiveFormsModule)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular2-forms

I was trying use simple array form in angular 4, And I came across a strange problem with ngModel .

Have a lock on my codes first please.

## My Method

1. Defining my form FormGroup:

   ```
   public invoiceForm: FormGroup;
   ```
2. Setting my testing Data and Form Model:

   ```
   readonly local = [
   'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
   'et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit',
   'Epsum factorial non deposit',
   'Ma quande lingues coalesce'
   ];
   public localModel = this.local;
   ```
3. Define form group in ngOnInit and simple add my locals row into form group:

   ```
   this.invoiceForm = this._fb.group({
       itemRows: this._fb.array([this.initItemRows()])
   });


   for (let index in this.local)
       this.setAndReplaceNewERow(+index)
   ```

For now, Everything looks right.
[see result as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYekW.png)

## The Problem

When I change one of the text inputs, The main variable will also change.

Before Change :

```
FormGroup
{
  "itemRows": [
    {
      "itemname": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },
    {
      "itemname": "et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit"
    },
    {
      "itemname": "Epsum factorial non deposit"
    },
    {
      "itemname": "Ma quande lingues coalesce"
    }
  ]
}

My Local Data
[
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
  "et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit",
  "Epsum factorial non deposit",
  "Ma quande lingues coalesce"
]

My Form Model
[
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
  "et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit",
  "Epsum factorial non deposit",
  "Ma quande lingues coalesce"
]
```

After change :

```
FormGroup
{
  "itemRows": [
    {
      "itemname": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },
    {
      "itemname": "et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit"
    },
    {
      "itemname": "changed !!!!!!!!!!!"
    },
    {
      "itemname": "Ma quande lingues coalesce"
    }
  ]
}
My Local Data
[
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
  "et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit",
  "changed !!!!!!!!!!!",
  "Ma quande lingues coalesce"
]
My Form Model
[
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
  "et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit",
  "changed !!!!!!!!!!!",
  "Ma quande lingues coalesce"
]
```

## DEMO

Please take a look at [Plunk Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5sNyDiht6g79LljuCcMo?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want your `readonly local` variable to remain the same ?

You just need to change this :

```
public localModel = this.local;
```

to this :

```
public localModel = Object.assign({}, this.local);
```

---

**What's happening here :** Your localModel gets the same reference as your `local` variable, and then affect this to model to your form. Thus, modifying the data in the form will modify the reference and thus your `local` variable value will change.

I use the `Object.assign()` method to create a new reference, with the same value. Basically, it's a copy.

**N.B :** If you use arrays, you will have the same issues, as the array reference will be the same. Therefore, you might need to do what is called a **Deep Copy** to create a new reference of the array, as well as a copy of your values inside it.

Comment: Thank you Alex. That was exactly what I wanted.